# Why return -1.#IND00 for pow(x, 1.0/3.0) when x is negative?

Tags: c

I try to `pow(x, 1.0/3.0)` and get -1.#IND00, why does it happens?

I tried to do `pow(x, 1./3)`, `pow(x, (1.0/3.0))`, but nothing positive.

It doesn't works only when x less than 0. And x is float.

Example:

```
   x = -3.12;
   y = pow(x, 1.0 / 3.0);
   printf("%f", y);
```

The code above prints y as -1.#IND00

Comment: What is the value of `x`?

Comment: What is `x`? Please provide a minimal working example of what you want to do and the expected Vs the actual output

Comment: My guess: `double x;` and it's never initialized.

Comment: C has a [`cbrt()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cbrt), btw.

Comment: post a [mcve] please

Comment: What value do you expect to get?

Comment: In my example i expected to get - 1.461229 in y var.

Comment: Even if `pow` *were* defined to compute real roots of negative numbers (which it is not), it would not be able to compute cube roots of negative numbers like this, because the rational number 1/3 cannot be represented exactly as type `double` (just as it cannot be represented exactly in decimal).  So you'd actually be raising your negative number to approximately the 0.333333333333333315 power, and it would have a small, imaginary part, i.e. it would not be representable as a real number, let alone as a `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pow` function doesn't compute roots of negative numbers.

Section 7.12.7.4p1-2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `pow` functions states:

> *1.* `double pow(double x, double y);`
>
> *2.* The `pow` functions compute `x` raised to the power `y`.  A domain error occurs if `x` is finite and negative and `y` is finite and
> not an integer value

So the values you're giving constitute a **domain error**, which is described in section 7.12.1p2:

> For all functions, a *domain error* occurs if an input argument is outside the domain over
> which the mathematical function is defined. ...  On a
> domain error, the function returns an implementation-defined value

If you want to compute the cube root of a number, you should instead use `cbrt` which accepts negative values.

Answer (score 0):

The power function with negative base is defined in the real numbers only when the exponent is integer. The operation `-3.12^0.3` is not defined in mathematics (in real numbers).<sup>*</sup>

This fact is described in the [documentation of `pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow#Error_handling):

> If base is finite and negative and exponent is finite and non-integer, a domain error occurs and a range error may occur.

---

<sup>*</sup> This is technically not quite correct but for most exponents the value of `x^y` when `x` is negative is a complex number, not a real number.